# JWT setExpiration for servers time zone Android

Tags: android, date, timezone, jwt, jodatime

I'm trying to set up a short expiration time for my JWT web token.  Problem I'm running into is if the client is in a different time zone the server (EST). Currently the working code is as follows.

```
Map<String, Object> header = new HashMap<>();
header.put("typ", Header.JWT_TYPE);
long now = Instant.now().getMillis();
String compactJws = Jwts.builder()
        .setHeader(header)
        .claim("email", email)
        .claim("password", password)
        .claim("reg_id", reg_id)
        .claim("deviceId", deviceId)
        .claim("gsf", returnGSF())
        .claim("imei", returnIMEI())
        .claim("serial", Build.SERIAL)
        .claim("version", String.valueOf(version))
        .claim("language", language)
        .setIssuedAt(new Date(now))
        .setExpiration(new Date(now + 60000))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, settings.getString("keychain", "password"))
        .compact();
```

Sixty Seconds is plenty of leeway. I'm pulling my hair out with all the different Date/Format object variants. How to get the date object for US eastern time regardless of the devices location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JWT timestamps are always UTC-based, so time zone is not your problem.

It's quite possible the client and server clocks are not in sync.  60 seconds is not much tolerance for clock skew.  Other protocols use much larger variances.  For example Kerberos allows a default of 5 minutes delta between clocks.

Comment: The server decides token is expired if the ttl is anything  than hours. Changing the client devices time to anything other than Eastern to simulate different time zones results in token exspired immediately

Comment: `Instant` is UTC-based.  So is `Date`.  So are JWTs.  So nothing in your chain should be affected by client time zone.  Something else must be going on elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Even Jwts `setIssuedAt` if you dig through deep enough just calls `getTime` on that date object, so nowhere is it applying the local time zone.

Comment: Is the timezone of the server location irrelevant? It simply uses firebase/JWT-PHP to decode the token. I know for a fact all of it's SQL timestamps are EST

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it is the answer to the question I should of asked. JWT is passed a Date object which is based on UTC

Comment: So i have no choice but to depend on the PHP JWT firebase library to automatically know to compare the token with a UTC timestamp on the server side